# Solve for a single variable that is used as a exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have an equation like this:

$y = x + (-1)^x$

How do I solve for $x$?

If there were not the $x + ...$ I could just take the logarithm of both sides to separate the $x$ from the $-1$.

Comment: Is $x$ any real number or an integer?

Comment: sorry, integer.

Comment: What do you mean solve? Do you want to write x in terms of y or do you want to find the zeroes?

Comment: yes but i mean how would you write the equation such that $x = ...$. edit: x in terms of y

Comment: by the intermediate value theorem and horizontal line test, there is no continuous inverse  :( so you'll have to go with @AnuragA said

Comment: oh that makes sense. i can see how if it were continuous, it would not be one to one and not have an inverse function. @AnuragA can you please post you answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, so consider two cases: $x$ is odd and $x$ is even. Then
$$
x=\begin{cases}y+1 & \text{ if } x \text{ is odd}\\y-1 & \text{ if } x \text{ is even} \end{cases}.
$$
OR we can also write this as
$$
x=\begin{cases}y+1 & \text{ if } y \text{ is even}\\y-1 & \text{ if } y \text{ is odd} \end{cases}.
$$

Comment: It would be better to write the condition as depending on the parity of $y$, so the first line would be if $y$ is even.

Comment: @RossMillikan Your suggestion is quite appropriate but when I had put this as a comment, OP wanted everything in terms of $x$, hence the ''odd'' looking answer.

Comment: I don't see  the comments-maybe they have been deleted.  I like the two way approach.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative way of expressing the answer might illuminate what is going on: $f(2n)=2n+1; f(2n+1)=2n$. This is a transposition which switches adjacent odd and even integers.

By hand, if $f(x)=y$ then $x=y+(-1)^y$ - so the function is its own inverse, as you would expect from a transposition.